# Create Executable from Linux using Qt 5, C++ and OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, qt5, cross-platform, executable

I've been trying to deploy an executable version of my program, I tried in many ways as

1. Running it in **release mode**
2. **linuxdeployqt** tool
3. **GitHub + Jenkins**

but those hasn't worked for me, I can deploy the program in the development enviroment, but I need to install it in different computers. If if's possible to create the version for Windows (Because the university I developed it for is asking for it)

I'm using Qt 5.9.5, gcc 7.5.0, CMake 3.10.2, GDB 8.1.0, OpenCV 4.1.1 and SO Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to try using CQtDeployer from https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer

You can find instalation guide in [this video](https://youtu.be/JroXadNeTXw?t=321) , even though it isn't in english language, everything is described step by step in there.

Hope that would work for you.

Comment: It's strange, I had to do the first steps to create the executable for CQT, but after deploying as she did as the first step didn't create the main executable needed for the next steps.

Comment: Any error messages? if you're getting troubles installing CQT on your system, there is also installation guide on Github page i've mentioned above.

Comment: No, only the warnings I had prior (but still works when running it on qt)

Comment: You can download .run file of CQT for your Linux system from [here](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/releases/tag/1.4.4)

Comment: The problem is before that, She said that CQT needed the executable created, which I think is the one she created at minute 1:10. I installed CQT correctly, but when I run the cqt command there are these errors: * *Error: setTargetDir fail!
Error: deploy is failed!* *

Comment: On time code 1:10 what she is doing is creating executable of her project in release mode from console, when you run your program from qtcreator it automatically creates that exe in specific folder(path defined in qtcreator/tools/Options/Build & Run/ build directory) for default it is same directory as your project is with "build-" prefix.

Comment: That's what doesn't work, I have ran qtcreator and it doesn't create it, I looked up all 3 folders (Project, Build and Release)

Comment: Ok,i understand you. Also when you hit the run button, program starts running or not?

Comment: I think I found what I had messed up, I had declared the Target beforehand without knowing it was the exe, so it was in another folder and with another name. Now I'll create add all the libraries to the correct folder. Thank you very much! (Por cierto, hablo Español, hehe)

Answer (score 0):

How to deploy project with cqtdeployer.

1. First one you need to install cqtdeployer into your platform

   - Snap (14 more linux destributions):

   ```
   sudo snap install cqtdeployer
   ```

   Or

   Install from snap store and add all requirement permissions.

   [image: Download from Snap Store]

   - Other linux [LinuxInstaller.run](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/releases).

   ```
   chmod +x LinuxInstaller.run
   ./LinuxInstaller.run
   ```

   - Windows [installer](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/releases)
2. Build your project on release mode.
3. Deploy yor executable file.

   - For Linux systems:

   ```sh
   cqtdeployer -bin myexecutable
   ```

   - For Windows systems:

   ```sh
   cqtdeployer -bin myexecutable.exe -qmake C:/Qt/5.15.0/min_gw/bin/qmake.exe
   ```

   - For crossplatform build (Linux -> Windows)

   ```sh
   cqtdeployer -bin myexecutable.exe -qmake ~/crossbuildet-Qt/5.15.0/min_gw/bin/qmake
   ```

### Extra options

If you use extra libraries. just add path for cqtdeployer to used libs.

```sh
cqtdeployer -bin myexecutable -libDir /PathToMyExtraLibs
```

If you want find libraryes recursive from libDir path, just add recursiveDepth option.

```sh
cqtdeployer -bin myexecutable -libDir /PathToMyExtraLibs -recursiveDepth 5
```

If you application use qml, just add qmlDir option

```sh
cqtdeployer -bin myexecutable -libDir /PathToMyExtraLibs -recursiveDepth 5 -qmlDir /path/to/my/qml/sources
```

If you want create simple installer for you application just add qif option.

```
cqtdeployer -bin myexecutable -libDir /PathToMyExtraLibs -recursiveDepth 5 -qmlDir /path/to/my/qml/sources qif
```

If you use system libraries from system PATH, just add deploySystem option.

Warning: snap version do not have permision to system files. To deploy system libraries use the cqtdeployer version from the [installer](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/releases)

```
cqtdeployer -bin myexecutable -libDir /PathToMyExtraLibs -recursiveDepth 5 -qmlDir /path/to/my/qml/sources qif deploySystem
```

#### If you have any problems with use cqtdeployer then ask you questions on the official github issues [page](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/issues).

#### For more options of CQtDeploye see oficial [documentation](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/wiki/Options).

Comment: Thank you very much, but I couldn't find the crossplatform builder, and the using directories to everything I need it still send me that I should use the DistributionKit as default target, then I use it, and still says that I should use it, do you know what's going on?

Comment: For building crossplatdorm, you need to build Qt and requariment libraryes (OpenCV) from source with a crossplatform compilation mingw-w64 [see this article](https://uncannier.com/cross-compile-qt-mingw-windows-applications-on-a-linux-host/).

A as for the target folder DistributionKit then it can be changed using the option:
**-targetDir /new/targetPath**